# How to safetly add a repository

Tags: linux, centos, yum, repository

To add a repository to my Centos server, I am doing the following:

```
wget -O /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6 https://www.fedoraproject.org/static/0608B895.txt
gpg --quiet --with-fingerprint /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
# Configure priorities per the documentation.
```

Questions...

1. Should I always save keys in `/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/` as I did above?  Note that http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge does not state to save the at all, but other documents do.
2. Is it up to me to come up with a name for the key (i.e.
   `RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6`?  Is there an accepted naming standard?
3. How do I identify the correct link for the key?  For instance, I am using https://www.fedoraproject.org/static/0608B895.txt, but I just used this key from some random tutorial, and don't know why it is the correct link.
4. How do I ensure the key is accurate?  I did `gpg --quiet
   --with-fingerprint /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6`, but what does that tell me?
5. Anything else I should be doing?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Download the RPM:

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

You can install the repository with one command if you have the RPM:

```
yum install epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

The installation copies the key to `/etc/pki/rpm-gpg` directory automatically.

The file name of the key is in the repo file in `/etc/yum.repos.d`

For example in `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` the following line says the GPG key is `/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6`

```
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
```